# Make a custom iOS calendar start from the correct starting day

Tags: ios, calendar

Our custom calendar must work with NSLocale and thus update to start from a Monday or Sunday depending on this locale.   The calendar is a custom grid filled with buttons.

I shift the display of actual days minus 1 and this seems fine, but the days themselves are proving a real pain to shift.

I would like to shift my numerical display of numbers to the correct day dependent upon the locale.

So, assuming it is Feb 2015, if Monday is the start of the week, the first Sunday should only ever display 1 and then Monday is 2.

However I can't get my buttons to respect this fact and ends up displaying days incorrectly for different days.

--- Edit ---

I'm nearly there now.  I've got it displaying things close to my expectation, however the first day never seems to display.

Please note this is before I've reviewed other suggestions (below)

```
 NSLocale *autoUpdating = [self getLocale];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setLocale:autoUpdating];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.month = self.currentMonth.month;
    components.year = self.currentMonth.year;
    components.day = 1;
    [components setWeekday:[calendar firstWeekday]];

    NSDate *firstDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    NSCalendarUnit units = (NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit);
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:units fromDate:firstDay];

    NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];
    __unused NSDate *minimumDate = self.minimumDate ?: today;

    NSDate *selected = nil;

    if (self.selectedDate) {
        selected = [calendar dateFromComponents:self.selectedDate];
    }

    NSUInteger startDay = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSUInteger currentDay = calendar.firstWeekday;

    NSRange dayRange = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:firstDay];


    for (UIButton *button in self.dayButtons) {

        button.selected = NO;

        if ( ((button.tag + 1) >= startDay) && (currentDay <= dayRange.length) ) {

            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(currentDay)];
            [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateDisabled];


            dateComponents.day = currentDay;
            NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

            if (selected && [date compare:selected] == NSOrderedSame) {
                button.selected = YES;
            }

            if ([date compare:minimumDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                button.enabled = NO;
            } else {
                button.enabled = YES;
            }


            currentDay++;
        } else {
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        }
```

[image: updated calendar]

The image I have included shows it is incorrect for Feburary and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you call `setWeekday:`  on `components` when trying to get `firstDay`? The first of the month is not always on the first weekday of the month for the locale.

Comment: Not sure. I've really not used dates before. Also, retro-fitting someone's elses code that always doing this

Comment: You've updated the code in your question so now my answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: My locale is `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de"];`

Comment: I had the original code somewhere and I tried your solution, it seems to work

Comment: Sorry about that, I was looking at incorrect month. Your solution seems to work correctly

Comment: Accepted @rmaddy answer